# Cast map<K, shared_ptr<V>> to map<K, shared_ptr<const V>>?

Tags: c++, casting, constants

I'm storing an `std::map` of `std::shared_ptr<V>` as value.

From one functions, I want to return a reference to this map, but with `std::shared_ptr<const V>` as value type, is that possible ?

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct A {
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<int>> map;

    const std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<const int>>& ret1() const {
        return map;
    }
};
```

But this code fails to compile:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 
'const std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<const int> >&' 
from expression of type 'const std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<int> >'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type `T` and a type `const T` are related but ultimately different types. If you don't want the caller of `ret1` to modify the values in your map, then either return a copy of the map, or accept a reference to a map as argument and copy the keys and values into that.